# How to make sure the running order of puppet classes?

Tags: ruby, deployment, puppet

I am new to puppet deployment. I have two classes defined

```
class taskname{
      exec{ "deploy_script":
         command = "cp ${old_path} ${new path}",
         user = root,
      }

      cron{"cron_script2":
         command = "pyrhton ${new_path}",
         user = root,
         require = Exec["deploy_script"]
       }

 }

class taksname2{

      exec{ "deploy_script2":
         command = "cp ${old_path} ${new path}",
         user = root,
      }

      cron{"cron_script":
         command = "pyrhton ${new_path}",
         user = root,
         require = Exec["deploy_script2"]
       }



}
```

How do I make sure the running order of these two classes.
I have tried in a new manifest file

init.pp  to include these two classes

```
include taskname
include taskname2
```

It seems that second task running before the first task. How to I enforce the running order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use one of these metaparameters](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html).

> So to sum up: whenever a resource depends on another resource, use the
>   `before` or `require` metaparameter or chain the resources with `->`.
>   Whenever a resource needs to refresh when another resource changes,
>   use the `notify` or `subscribe` metaparameter or chain the resources with
>   `~>`. Some resources will autorequire other resources if they see them,
>   which can save you some effort.

[Also works for classes declared with a resource-like syntax](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_classes.html#metaparameters).

> When declared with the resource-like syntax, a class may use any
>   metaparameter. In such cases, every resource contained in the class
>   will also have that metaparameter. So if you declare a class with `noop
>   => true`, every resource in the class will also have `noop => true`, 
>   unless they specifically override it. Metaparameters which can take
>   more than one value (like the relationship metaparameters) will merge
>   the values from the container and any specific values from the
>   individual resource.

Comment: I understand the this order between functions inside a class, but how about ordering between classes?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the metaparameter `->` to specify a dependency relationship between the classes.  In init.pp where you declare/instantiate these classes, replace the include statements with parameterized class syntax:

```
class {"taskname":} ->
class {"taskname2":}
```

This will ensure `taskname` is invoked before `taskname2`.  For more information, see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/parameterized_classes.html#declaring-a-parameterized-class